# How to grab control collection like the Table class does?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

How do I grab the controls inside of a UserControl tag?

So if this is on a Page:

```
<ME:NewControl ID="tblCustomList" runat="server">
// ... these controls will be used in my UserControl.aspx
</ME:NewControl>
```

How do I access those controls in my UserControl?

For instance, the Table class does this:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblNormal" runat="server">
  <asp:TableRow>
      <asp:TableCell>Thing 1</asp:TableCell>
      <asp:TableCell>Thing 2</asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

I get an error saying my UserControl "does not have a public property named 'TableRow', when I do this:

```
<ME:NewControl ID="tblCustomList" runat="server">
  <asp:TableRow>
      <asp:TableCell>Thing 1</asp:TableCell>
      <asp:TableCell>Thing 2</asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
</ME:NewControl>
```

I found [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.createcontrolcollection.aspx) to help extend the Table class, but it's not *exactly* what I want to do.

I also found [this description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx) of how to use Templated Controls, which I'm not sure if I can use.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you want to under your user control be able to add rows?  Or find the rows that have been added?

Comment: Maybe I should rework the question: I want the rows I add between my UserControl tags above to insert inside the UserControl below - does that make sense?

Comment: I just reworked the question entirely to make it more straightforward (revision 5 in edit log)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed something like this:

```
public TableRow DTHeader { get; set; }

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    tblCollection.Rows.Add(DTHeader);
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

And then use this on my Page:

```
<ME:NewControl ID="tblCustomList" runat="server">
    <DTHeader>
        <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
        //...
    </DTHeader>
</ME:NewControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question 100%.

However if you a custom control called Row you can add a collection to the main table user control.

You can do this with a generic list.  This should give you the ability to add them like a normal aspx control.

I don't have a code sample here, but I have done it many times.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your question.

You could access the controls server side by just using tblCustomList.Controls and then you could loop and add to your usercontrol. But again, i am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear that the code above would actually go on the page.  I'll also include the error message I'm getting in a second here.

Answer (score 0):

The [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.createcontrolcollection.aspx) that you referenced seems to be what you're trying to accomplish.
Have you added the following to the code behind?

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Samples.AspNet.CS.Controls
{
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, 
        Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
    public sealed class CustomTableCreateControlCollection : Table
    {
        protected override ControlCollection CreateControlCollection()
        {
            // Return a new ControlCollection
            return new ControlCollection(this);
        }
    }
}
```